# Access a view controller instantiated by segue from app delegate

Tags: ios7, uitabbarcontroller, uistoryboard, uistoryboardsegue, appdelegate

I'm following [this ray wenderlich tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/5191/beginning-storyboards-in-ios-5-part-2).

My storyboard image is given below:

[image]

How can I access playerDetailsViewcontroller from the app delegate? I am able to pass data  from playersViewController to playerDetailsViewController using segue. But I have a requirement to access playerDetailsViewcontroller from the app delegate. Is there a way to access a view controller from the app delegate using the segue id?